# Jenkins Github SSH pipeline not working

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

I have build a small Helloworld node application. The idea is to push the code to a Github server which then sends a notification (webhook) to a Jenkins server which will build the code. This part works good. I then also want to deploy the code to a server over SSH every time Jenkins has been building successful. I can't get this step to work.

To be able to deploy the code using SSH, I have written a small shell script (note I have the SSH agent plugin installed and configured correctly a credential with a private key):

```
#---Contents of /script/deploy-dev.sh---

ssh username@<IP_OF_MY_SERVER> <<EOF
cd ~/HelloWorld
sudo git pull
sudo npm install --production
sudo forever restartall
exit
EOF
```

I put the following code in the "Execute shell" box (as part of the build)

```
npm install
./script/test
./script/deploy-dev.sh
```

The first two lines work well and result in a successfull build. Adding the last line gives me following error message:

*Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
02:33:38 sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified*

Any suggestion?

Note: I'm in fact following [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-continuous-integration-continuous-deployment-with-jenkins--cms-21511) tutorial but it suggests to select the 'build when pushed to Github' for which the Github plugin is needed and as this is an enterprise Jenkins I can't add plugins. Only have SSH-agent so would like to use that one

Comment: It looks like you haven't got passwordless sudo configured on the target server.  `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` is because sudo is requiring a password, but has no way to ask you for it.  Can you ssh into the machine manually and try to do a sudo command to confirm this?

Comment: Yes you were fully right. I gave the user passwords less Suso and this fixed it!

Comment: Good, I've added that as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't got passwordless sudo configured on the target server. `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` is because sudo is requiring a password, but has no way to ask you for it.

Have a look here https://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux for details on how to set that up.